# How do I stop my eyelet curtains from rattling on the curtain pole when the window is open

Tags: bedroom

We sleep with the bedroom window open and if there is any breeze outside the curtain rings rattle on the curtain pole.  Any ideas how I could stop this apart from the obvious of closing the window.

Comment: A video of this in action would be very helpful

Comment: Leave the curtains open and wear a sleep mask instead?

Answer (score 3):

Metal against metal can be noisy and distracting.

One simple HACK would be to put a thin strip of plastic electrical tape along the top of the curtain rod. Try to position it so it does not show when the rod is in position for use.

The plastic tape will provide a smooth layer for the eyelets to slide over yet enough to insulate the metal parts from making noise where they may touch.

Total time for application: 15 - 20 minutes.

Stand on something stable when reaching to position your curtains.

Good luck.

Comment: I'd perhaps add that the tape may need periodic replacement as it ages/the curtain rings nick it and it starts presenting a barrier to smooth movement rather than assisting it (which may then cause a cycle of the user ragging on the curtains, worsening the problem). A more permanent fix may be possible by sheathing the curtain pole with a plastic pipe from a hardware store, or even just replacing the pole with eg a wooden one